# Compensating for "variance" in a survey

Tags: python, nlp, fuzzy-comparison

The title for this one was quite tricky.

I'm trying to solve a scenario, 
Imagine a survey was sent out to XXXXX amount of people, asking them what their favourite football club was. 
From the response back, it's obvious that while many are favourites of the same club, they all "expressed" it in different ways. 
For example,

For Manchester United, some variations include...

- Man U
- Man Utd.
- Man Utd.
- Manchester U
- Manchester Utd

All are obviously the same club however, if using a simple technique, of just trying to get an extract string match, each would be a separate result.

Now, if we further complication the scenario, let's say that because of the sheer volume of different clubs (eg. Man City, as M. City, Manchester City, etc), again plagued with this problem, its impossible to manually "enter" these variances and use that to create a custom filter such that converters all Man U -> Manchester United, Man Utd. > Manchester United, etc. But instead we want to automate this filter, to look for the most likely match and converter the data accordingly.

I'm trying to do this in Python (from a .cvs file) however welcome any pseudo answers that outline a good approach to solving this.

**Edit: Some additional information**
This isn't working off a set list of clubs, the idea is to "cluster" the ones we have together.
The assumption is there are no spelling mistakes. 
There is no assumed length of how many clubs
And the survey list is long. Long enough that it doesn't warranty doing this manually (1000s of queries)

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is either "reconciliation of data" or "normalisation of data". Reconciliation is matching to a know good list, normalisation is making the answers all the same.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to put some terms behind it.

Comment: Nobody suggested "doing this manually". What are "queries" in this context? How many thousands? 2 or 999? As previously requested, how many *unique* values after light normalisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Refine does just this, but I'll assume you want to roll your own.

Note, difflib is built into Python, and has lots of features (including eliminating junk elements). I'd start with that.

You probably don't want to do it in a completely automated fashion. I'd do something like this:

```
# load corrections file, mapping user input -> output
# load survey
import difflib

possible_values = corrections.values()

for answer in survey:
    output = corrections.get(answer,None)
    if output = None:
        likely_outputs = difflib.get_close_matches(input,possible_values)
        output = get_user_to_select_output_or_add_new(likely_outputs)
        corrections[answer] = output
        possible_values.append(output)
save_corrections_as_csv
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing towards the difflib library (also Google Refine)! Looks like a lot of useful function in there. I'm gonna have a good play around.

Comment: @Cam: difflib is designed for use on source files, not data. It is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could convert many of these into a standard form by taking the string, lower-casing it, removing all punctuation, then comparing the start of each word.

If you had a list of all the actual club names, you could compare directly against that as well; and for strings which don't match first-n-letters to any actual team, you could try lexigraphical comparison against any of the returned strings which actually do match.

It's not perfect, but it should get you 99% of the way there.

```
import string

def words(s):
    s = s.lower().strip(string.punctuation)
    return s.split()

def bestMatchingWord(word, matchWords):
    score,best = 0., ''
    for matchWord in matchWords:
        matchScore = sum(w==m for w,m in zip(word,matchWord)) / (len(word) + 0.01)
        if matchScore > score:
            score,best = matchScore,matchWord
    return score,best

def bestMatchingSentence(wordList, matchSentences):
    score,best = 0., []
    for matchSentence in matchSentences:
        total,words = 0., []
        for word in wordList:
            s,w = bestMatchingWord(word,matchSentence)
            total += s
            words.append(w)
        if total > score:
            score,best = total,words
    return score,best

def main():
    data = (
        "Man U",
        "Man. Utd.",
        "Manch Utd",
        "Manchester U",
        "Manchester Utd"
    )

    teamList = (
        ('arsenal',),
        ('aston', 'villa'),
        ('birmingham', 'city', 'bham'),
        ('blackburn', 'rovers', 'bburn'),
        ('blackpool', 'bpool'),
        ('bolton', 'wanderers'),
        ('chelsea',),
        ('everton',),
        ('fulham',),
        ('liverpool',),
        ('manchester', 'city', 'cty'),
        ('manchester', 'united', 'utd'),
        ('newcastle', 'united', 'utd'),
        ('stoke', 'city'),
        ('sunderland',),
        ('tottenham', 'hotspur'),
        ('west', 'bromwich', 'albion'),
        ('west', 'ham', 'united', 'utd'),
        ('wigan', 'athletic'),
        ('wolverhampton', 'wanderers')
    )

    for d in data:
        print "{0:20} {1}".format(d, bestMatchingSentence(words(d), teamList))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

run on sample data gets you

```
Man U                (1.9867767507647776, ['manchester', 'united'])
Man. Utd.            (1.7448074166742613, ['manchester', 'utd'])
Manch Utd            (1.9946817328797555, ['manchester', 'utd'])
Manchester U         (1.989100008901989, ['manchester', 'united'])
Manchester Utd       (1.9956787398647866, ['manchester', 'utd'])
```

Comment: -1 syntax error in print statement. Please paste code that you actually ran. Don't make it up.

Comment: @John Machin: flying bloody hell, it's got an extra quotation mark, lighten the frick up already.

Comment: One byte or a hundred, it's just "fricking" careless.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question with answers to the following:

You say "we want to automate this filter, to look for the most likely match" -- match to what?? Do you have a list of the standard names of all of the possible football clubs, or do the many variations of each name need to be clustered to create such a list?

How many clubs?

How many survey responses?

After doing very light normalisation (replace `.` by space, strip leading/trailing whitespace, replace runs of whitespace by a single space, convert to lower case [in that order]) and counting, how many unique responses do you have?

Your focus seems to be on abbreviations of the standard name. Do you need to cope with nicknames e.g. Gunners -> Arsenal, Spurs -> Tottenham Hotspur? Acronyms (WBA -> West Bromwich Albion)? What about spelling mistakes, keyboard mistakes, SMS-dialect, ...? In general, what studies of your data have you done and what were the results?

You say """its impossible to manually "enter" these variances""" -- is it possible/permissible to "enter" some "variances" e.g. to cope with nicknames as above?

What are your criteria for success in this exercise, and how will you measure it?

Comment: Ok, I shall edit it accordingly. The exercise is under the assumption that there NOT a setlist of know football clubs, that the goal is too cluster groups together of the most likely matches (and ignored similar, but not matching results, eg Man City =/= Man United).  There is an assumption, of no spelling mistakes, but acronyms may be present (again messy data). Ultimately the successes is measured on how well the code is able to deal with the various variations and how effectively groups the data (and renames the clubs to a standard format)

Comment: "exercise" and "assumption" tend to indicate homework. Is it? "There is an assumption of no spelling mistakes" indicates somebody is not in the real world. There either are spelling mistakes (99.99% chance, in the real world) or there are not. Please answer the question """what studies of your data have you done and what were the results?"""

Comment: Ok, I think my message is coming across quite muddled. By exercise I mean, this is a scenario I've created to try and learn more about python (it's not homework or an assignment). I'm very simply generated a long list, of a known number of (300)  the various Manchester strings (Man. Utd, Man. United, etc) alongside side 20x Arsenal, Birmingham, Liverpool and Newcastle. So there are only 5 different names/clubs. It's just meant to be a "trial" experiment to get a better understanding of how to approach "messy" data and process it.

Comment: So the ideal output would be, a count of 300 Manchester United (doesn't matter what its labelled, as long as its a single entity) and 20 Arsenal, 20 Birmingham, 20 Liverpool, 20 Newcastle.

Comment: @Cam: Your generated list is far from reality. Get yourself some real world data. Forget "assumptions".